# How is CMOS impedance calculated?

Tags: cmos

The following is a snippet from the book *Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits*

[image]

Here is what I thought.

[image]

$$V_1 = 0-V_x $$

$$V_{bs1} = 0 - V_{s1}$$

$$V_{s1} = I_x r_{o1}$$

According to KCL.

$$ g_{m1} V_1 + g_{mb1} V_{bs1} = I_x $$

We can use those equation we got earlier to replace \$V_{1}, V_{bs1}\$.

Finally we can derive the equation.

$$R_{eq} = \frac{V_x} {I_x} = - \frac{1 + g_{mb1} r_{o1}} {g_{m1}}$$.

However, the book gave the following.

$$R_{eq} = r_{o1} \parallel \frac{1}{g_{mb1}} \parallel \frac{1}{g_{m1}}$$

Comment: @Neil_UK Thank you for editing, bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equivalent circuit is wrong. Your job is to find \$R_{eq}\$.
This \$R_{eq}\$ is the small-signal resistance seen from \$M_1\$ source terminal when we are looking into the source terminal when \$V_{IN} = 0\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXWgg0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$R_{eq} = \frac{V_X}{I_X}\$

Thus, the equivalent small-signal model will look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr5E56.png)</sup>

And to find the thevenin voltage \$V_{TH} = V_{in,eq}\$.
You need to find the voltage gain of this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftRT07.png)</sup>

$$V_{out} = \biggl( g_{m1} (V_{in} - V_{out}) - g_{mb1} V_{out}) \biggl) r_{o1}$$

$$\Rightarrow V_{out} = \frac{g_{m1} r_{o1}} {1+(g_{m1} + g_{mb1}) r_{o1}} V_{in}$$

$$\Rightarrow V_{th} = V_{out} = \frac{g_{m1} r_{o1}} {1+(g_{m1} + g_{mb1}) r_{o1}} V_{in}$$

Comment: Are you sure the voltage of gate -source is Vx?

Comment: There is also a thevenin voltage from the book, how can calculate it out?

Comment: This is a P-MOS thus the Vsg voltage controls the drain current. In this circuit we have Vs = Vx and Vg = 0V thus, Vx = Vsg.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to calculate this thevenin equivalent voltahge?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: I have submitted the thevenin voltage equation for you to review.

Comment: Nice try, but it seems that you have missed the ro1 resistance in the denominator.

Comment: I have just corrected the problem you pointed out

Comment: But I don't see any change in my answer.

Comment: Have you refreshed you browser? I added ro1 to the denominator

Comment: Now I see it. I had to approve your changes to be able to see them.