# How can this circuit remove \$R_{D2}\$ in small signal analysis for this nmos?

Tags: cmos

The following is differential pair small signal analysis from the book *Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits*.

Let us set \$V_{in2}\$ to zero and find the effect of Vin1 at X and Y [Fig. 4.17(a)]. To obtain \$V_X\$ , we note that
M1 forms a common-source stage with a degeneration resistance equal to the impedance seen looking
into the source of M2 [Fig. 4.17(b)]. Neglecting channel-length modulation and body effect, we have
\$R_S = 1/g_{m2}\$
The following is analysis of differential pairs. How can this circuit remove \$R_{D2}\$ in (c)?

[image]

This is what I thought about

[image]

Comment: Can you explain to us why do you think that you should include the Rd2 resistor? Notice that in this case, M2 is working as a common-gate amplifier. What is Rin of a CG stage?

Comment: @G36 M2 is seen as a resistor \$R_S\$. Which transistor of  \$R_{in}\$ you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, M2 is seen as a resistor Rs. This Rs resistance is equal to the input resistance of a CG stage. Because in this case M2 is working as a common-gate amplifier.

Comment: @G36 M2 is in series with \$R_{D2}\$. Why should we remove \$R_{D2}\$?

Comment: Find Rin of a CG state (also do not forget to neglect channel-length modulation) and you will see why.  Or try to find Rin in a circuit that contains an ideal current source in series with a resistor.  And you will see that a series resistor does not influence the current.

Answer (score 0):

The following is Thevenin analysis.

[image]

$$g_m  V_T = I_T$$

$$\frac{V_T} {I_T} = 1 / g_m$$

For Thevenin voltage

[image]

$$V_{eq} = V_T$$
$$g_m (V_T- V_{eq}) = 0$$
So current source is zero.

Comment: So, do you see now why we do not include Rd2 in Rin equation?

Comment: @G36 Thank you. Is Thevenin \$V_{eq}\$ same as \$V_{in}\$?

Comment: To be honest I do not understand what you are trying to achieve involving thevenin's voltage here.  For what purpose.

Comment: @G36 In last example we have to calculate  Veq https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691011/how-is-cmos-impedance-calculated

Comment: But we do not have to do it here because Vin2 = 0V (M2 gate is at AC GND).

Comment: @G36 Thank you for  you help. I really struggle with analog circuit analysis

Comment: I think that you should focus more on the intuitive understanding of what is going on in the circuit the the math itself.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355899/how-is-possible-that-with-same-ibase-there-is-more-than-one-vce/355955#355955 ; https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/410972/why-is-there-no-phase-shift-in-cc-and-cb-configuration/411171#411171 ;  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301617/bjt-input-ac-signal-amplitude/301642#301642